# Is there any benefit of having (id)sender in IBAction

Tags: cocoa, ibaction, target-action

When coding with cocoa I've noticed that it's not necessary to have `sender` parameter when defining `IBAction`, hence following action:

```
- (IBAction)showUserInfo:(id)sender;
```

can be declared as

```
- (IBAction)showUserInfo;
```

So I'm wondering if there is any other benefit besides having the button/menu item that sent the action? Only other situation I can think of is having few objects calling same IBAction. Anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be handy to use the `sender` argument when you're connecting the method to UI objects whose values can change and you may need to work with.

For instance if I wired up a method to a `UISegmentedControl` and set it's control event to UIControlEventValueChanged, I can use the object passed as the `sender:` argument to obtain it's selected segment index and then, based on the value, make a change in the UI.

```
-(IBAction)segmentedControlValueChanged:(id)sender
{
    UISegmentedControl *control = (UISegmentedControl *)sender;

    // Show or hide views depending on the selected index of the segmented control.
    if (control.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
        someView.hidden = YES;
    else 
        someView.hidden = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW32) says,

> The *sender* parameter usually identifies the control sending the action message (although it can be another object substituted by the actual sender). The idea behind this is similar to a return address on a postcard. The target can query the sender for more information if it needs to.

The *sender* parameter helps if you want any data from it. For example, on UISegmentControl value change, as in @Mark Adams answer. So if you don't want any information from the sender, you can just omit it, as in your `- (IBAction)showUserInfo;` example.